# Time dependent solution to infinite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

A particle of mass $m$ is confined within an infinite, one-dimensional potential well, $U(x)$, of width $a$.
$$
U\left(x\right) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
         \infty  &\: x \leq \frac{-a}{2}, x \geq \frac{a}{2}\\
        0 &\: \frac{-a}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{a}{2}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

I have to find the normalised solutions of the time-independent Schrodinger equation.

I know that if it were $0 \leq x \leq a$ rather than $-a/2 \leq x \leq a/2$, the solution would be given by $\psi(x) = \sqrt{2/a}\sin(n\pi x/a)$.
So to find the solution when it is $-a/2 \leq x \leq a/2$, do you just replace $a$ with $a/2$ in the solution?

Comment: Yes, you can, because the situations you describe are just identical. ( only the scale changes)

Comment: You should edit the definition of U(x) so that the potential is infinite at x GREATER THAN a/2.   I tried to edit, but I couldn't find more than 8 characters to edit (silly rule for a math based exchange when a single character can change the meaning, such as < vs > ).

Comment: Every post on this website is a question, so it is un-necessary to indicate that the question is a question in the question's title. Please have a look at [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) giving useful tips on writing good question titles.

Comment: Crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1302724/11127

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't simply substitute.  What you can do is change $x$ with a linear shift:  $$x \rightarrow x+\frac{a}{2}.$$

But if this is homework, you'll need to show your instructor WHY this is the proper way to handle the situation.

Or you could solve the problem with the new boundary conditions, but be aware that you have two solutions which are possible.  One solution gives you the odd symmetry functions (symmetry about the mid-line of the potential), and the other solution gives you the even symmetry functions.